# Get all filtered rows of datatable to iterate using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am applying a css class for  filtered rows in dataTable using

```
 tableName.fnFilter( this.value, 0);
$(tableName.fnGetNodes()).addClass('diffColor');
```

But i need to iterate all the filtered rows in datatable .Is it possible.How i can do that.
  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
May be its helpful for you 

var oTable = $("#Mytable").dataTable({whatever discribing your datatable});
//After the declaration of your datatable : 

var rowToAdd = true;
oTable.$('tr').each(function(){
var td_index = 0;
$(this).children('td').each(function){
 if($(this).value == mynewdata[td_index])
    rowToAdd = false;
 td_index++;
}
});
if(rowToAdd)
    oTable.fnAddData([Name,Age,Link,Schema,Visite,Info]);
```